# I can't create another table with postgresql and node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../db");
const user = require("../models/userModel");
const employees = db.define("employees", {
  firstname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  userId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: user,
      key: "id",
    },
  },
});
employees.sync({ alter: true });

module.exports = employees;
```

Okay,so I have two tables already created, in my terminal they appear with create table if not exists but not for this table,but not for this table,I missed something? pg version :8.7.1

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: postgres,
  port: 5000,
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

db file

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? Some other indication?

Comment: Nothing happens,the table doesn't appear in pgAdmin

Comment: Can you share the "../db" fie you require? The logic (and the problem) seems to be there

Comment: Sure,I updated the code.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the definition itself. Are you sure that code is executing?

Comment: Yep..the function is not executed..you're right

Comment: you have any ideea why is not working, the code is looking the same in the first 2 schemas  ,why db.define is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`sync` is (ironically) an asynchronous operation. You need to `await` it:

```js
await employees.sync({ alter: true });
```

Comment: I tried..same, nothing happens.

Comment: but the function is not called, because I didn't get any error  about await is valid only in async functions, even my console.log is not seen.